# Why can not I get the input of these fields? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, function, backend, web-deployment

I have created a contact Form and I try to get the data of the name, email and message inputs trough a function when I trigger the Send Message button but the data do not print them out, are null, why?.

This is the name Field, the **name** class into the input
[image]

This is the email Field, the **email** class into the input

[image]

This is the Message Field, the class **message** into the text area.

[image]

This is the function that triggers

[image]

This are the fields

[image]

And I get this when I trigger the function through the Sens Message Button.

[image]

Why do not store the data and print them out?
Thank for you help guys.

Comment: Please don't post text content as images.

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question." - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You haven't added either and `id` or `name` attribute. It's a good idea to use the id rather than a class name for specific form elements as id's should be unique within the document but class names are designed not to be.

Comment: For inputs you should use `value` not `nodeValue`.

Comment: SORRY GUYS FOR THE IMAGES, WILL NOR DO THAT AGAIN. Thanks @phuzi, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `trigger()` function, you should change .nodeValue to .value, so you get:

```
function trigger() {
    let name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
    let email = document.querySelector('.email').value;
    let message = document.querySelector('.message').value;
};
```